# Displaying edit boxes which are above HTML controls in Silverlight

Tags: html, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to make a navigation/control panel for a Google Earth browser API.

So far, I've got a Silverlight application which covers the whole screen with two panels: one on top and one on the left in the traditional fashion.

The Google Earth `<div>` is above the Silverlight control, and takes the space in the middle.

This is all fine. However, if I want to display a child window in Silverlight (for example, some sort of edit field), it will be displayed under Google Earth and won't be visible to the user.

Is it at all possible to have any child windows appear "above" the Google Earth control, that is, above all other HTML elements on a page? If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Anthony, but this feels way too complex given the limited time I've got to do what I need to do.

Thus, I figured, the best (read: easiest to implement) way will be for any controls that need to "overlap" the GE plugin to hide the plugin using JavaScript. It's not elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do that is have a second Silverlight object element in your html which has a higher Z-Order (or is windowed).  You could create another Xap for this purpose and use the HTMLBridge and/or Local Messaging to communicate between your primary Xap and this supplemental child window xap.